# bath faucet is hot but shower head always turns cold

Tags: plumbing, bathroom, shower, water-heater, bathtub

My shower has a single lever that turns from right (cold) to left (hot). When the lower bath faucet runs the water comes out hot. But the upper showerhead never heats up. If I run the lower faucet until the water is hot and then pull the tab so water comes through the showerhead, it comes out hot. But after a few minutes starts turning cold again! Im at my wits end! what could cause this and how do I fix it?

Comment: Is there a little mesh somewhere (don't know if this is the proper english term) in the connection between the showerhead and the faucet? In my bathroom this mesh tends to collect a bit of grime from the plumbing which restricts the flow just enough so that the therm shuts off. Cleaning it resolves that problem for a couple of months in my case.

Comment: you have heat loss in the pipes going to the bathroom. The low-flow shower head doesn't pull enough hot water to overcome the thermal loss via rapid replenishment, while the much heavier flow of the faucet does. That also explains the slow/missing temp ramp-up from the head. It's all about time: how long water takes to get from the tank to your tub, and that time is lower the more flow you have. Insulate your pipes to decrease loss, get a higher-flow head (if possible these days) to decrease time, and increase your hot water temp to give it more time.